# Migrando proceso de hasheo de .net a oracle 11g

Tags: c#, oracle-11g, criptografía

Tengo que migrar el siguiente proceso de encriptacion 3Des de .net a oracle 11g

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
                    
public class Program
{
    private const string strKey = "H9p-S5m2Dh6Fe7Ls3-Qs1D2e4Z";
    public static void Main()
    {
        var strToEncrypt = "test";
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objDESCrypto = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider objHashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] byteHash, byteBuff;
        byteHash = objHashMD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strKey));
        Console.WriteLine("v_key net = "+BitConverter.ToString(byteHash).Replace("-",""));
        objHashMD5 = null;
        objDESCrypto.Key = byteHash;
        objDESCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
        byteBuff = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);
        Console.WriteLine("src net = "+BitConverter.ToString(byteBuff).Replace("-",""));
        var hashbyte = objDESCrypto.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("encrypted_str net = "+BitConverter.ToString(hashbyte).Replace("-",""));
    }
}
```

Cuyo resultado es

```
v_key net = 8B928C8346648BDDB14B627EFF4E66F1 
src net = 74657374
encrypted_str net = E2CDBA9EBA5E0DF5
```

Y en oracle hice lo siguiente

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY Criptografia AS
strKeyDataAD CONSTANT VARCHAR2(42) := 'H9p-S5m2Dh6Fe7Ls3-Qs1D2e4Z';
PROCEDURE EncryptDataAD(strToEncrypt IN VARCHAR2) AS
        l_mod_ecb pls_integer;
        v_key raw(32);
        encrypted_str VARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN
        l_mod_ecb := dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_3DES + dbms_crypto.CHAIN_ECB + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5 ;
        
        v_key := dbms_crypto.hash(
            utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strKeyDataAD),
            dbms_crypto.hash_md5
          );
        dbms_output.put_line('v_key oracle: '|| rawtohex(v_key));
        dbms_output.put_line('src oracle: '|| utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'));
        encrypted_str := dbms_crypto.encrypt(
                                  src => utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'),
                                  TYP => l_mod_ecb,
                                  key => v_key--,
                                  --iv => v_iv
                                  );
        dbms_output.put_line('encrypted_str oracle: '|| encrypted_str);
        --RETURN encrypted_str;
    END EncryptDataAD;
END Criptografia;
```

cuyo resultado es

```
v_key oracle: 8B928C8346648BDDB14B627EFF4E66F1
src oracle: 74657374
encrypted_str oracle: DAACB8AE2BAD038F
```

Como se puede ver tanto  v_key (el hash md5)  como src (el string pasado bytes) son iguales en .net y oracle, sin embargo el resultado de el 3des es distinto. No entiendo por qué.
Intenté poner otros padding en oracle (PAD_PKCS5, PAD_NONE y PAD_ZERO) y también intenté distintos chaining modifiers (CHAIN_ECB,CHAIN_CBC,CHAIN_CFB y CHAIN_OFB) pero en ninguno de los casos logré el mismo resultado que en .net.
Cual puede ser el motivo?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final el problema era que 3des requiere una key de 192bits pero le estaba poniendo una de 128, entonces .net rellena la key repitiendo los primeros 8 bytes mientras que oracle lo hace de alguna otra forma. La solución fue usar una key de 192 bits y ambos dieron el mismo resultado.

el código en sql terminó siendo algo como

```
    PROCEDURE EncryptDataAD(strToEncrypt IN VARCHAR2) AS
            l_mod_ecb pls_integer;
            v_key raw(32);
            iv_ raw(16);
            encrypted_str VARCHAR2(4000);
            encryptedBase64_str VARCHAR2(4000);
            encryptedBase64URL_str VARCHAR2(4000);
            decrypted_str VARCHAR2(4000);
        BEGIN
            l_mod_ecb := dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_3DES + dbms_crypto.CHAIN_ECB + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5 ;
             dbms_output.put_line('l_mod_ecb oracle: '|| l_mod_ecb);
            v_key := dbms_crypto.hash(
                utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strKeyDataAD, 'AL32UTF8'),
                dbms_crypto.hash_md5
              );
            dbms_output.put_line('v_key oracle: '|| (v_key));
            dbms_output.put_line('src oracle: '|| utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'));
            iv_ := hextoraw('0123456789ABCDEF');
            dbms_output.put_line('iv_ oracle: '|| iv_);
            encrypted_str := dbms_crypto.encrypt(
                                      src => utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'),
                                      typ => l_mod_ecb,
                                      --typ => dbms_crypto.DES3_CBC_PKCS5,
                                      key => hextoraw('8B928C8346648BDDB14B627EFF4E66F18B928C8346648BDD')
                                      --,iv => iv_
                                      );
            dbms_output.put_line('encrypted_str oracle: '|| encrypted_str);
            encryptedBase64_str := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(encrypted_str));
            encryptedBase64URL_str := utl_url.escape(url => encryptedBase64_str);
            dbms_output.put_line('encryptedBase64_str oracle: '|| encryptedBase64_str);
            dbms_output.put_line('URL_ENCODE oracle: '|| encryptedBase64URL_str);
            
            decrypted_str := dbms_crypto.decrypt(
                                      src => encrypted_str,
                                      typ => l_mod_ecb,
                                      --typ => dbms_crypto.DES3_CBC_PKCS5,
                                      key => v_key
                                      --,iv => iv_
                                      );
            
            dbms_output.put_line('decrypted_str oracle: '|| UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(decrypted_str,'AL32UTF8'));
        END EncryptDataAD;
```

Como se puede ver, terminé poniendo la key de 192 bits repitiendo los primeros 8 bytes

Comment: Edita la respuesta, coloca el código que resuelve la pregunta, de ese modo le das la calidad necesaria para que cualquier usuario que pase por la misma situación tenga una luz directa a la solución, de paso te conviertes en el héroe de todos ellos. Saludos :D